# bond failing to start the backup network card on failure of main one

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ethernet, bonding

Our production server has 4 network cards, linked 2 by 2 on 2 bonds.

External network: bond0 : eth0 up & running, eth1 active-backup
Internal network: bond1 : eth2 up & running, eth3 active-backup

We got at the same time failure of eth0 and eth2 :

```
Mar  3 10:38:16 localhost kernel: [93739227.917537] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: 0x000068b0: 0xe0011514, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Mar  3 10:38:16 localhost kernel: [93739227.930035] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: 0x000068e0: 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x0001c2cc
Mar  3 10:38:16 localhost kernel: [93739227.942529] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: 0x000068f0: 0x00ff000e, 0x00ff0000, 0x00000000, 0x04444444
...
Mar  3 10:38:17 localhost kernel: [93739228.141585] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: 4: NAPI info [0000000a:0000000a:(0000:0000:01ff):04dc:(04dc:04dc:0000:0000)]
Mar  3 10:38:17 localhost kernel: [93739228.201559] bonding: bond0: link status definitely down for interface eth0, disabling it
Mar  3 10:38:17 localhost kernel: [93739228.216343] tg3 0000:02:00.0 eth0: Link is down
Mar  3 10:38:18 localhost kernel: [93739229.253266] bonding: bond0: now running without any active interface !


Mar  3 10:38:18 localhost kernel: [93739229.253331] tg3 0000:08:00.0 eth2: transmit timed out, resetting
Mar  3 10:38:19 localhost kernel: [93739230.509553] tg3 0000:08:00.0 eth2: 0x00000000: 0x165f14e4, 0x00100406, 0x02000000, 0x00800010
Mar  3 10:38:19 localhost kernel: [93739230.521603] tg3 0000:08:00.0 eth2: 0x00000010: 0xd90a000c, 0x00000000, 0xd90b000c, 0x00000000
Mar  3 10:38:19 localhost kernel: [93739230.533658] tg3 0000:08:00.0 eth2: 0x00000020: 0xd90c000c, 0x00000000, 0x00000000, 0x200314e4
Mar  3 10:38:19 localhost kernel: [93739230.545704] tg3 0000:08:00.0 eth2: 0x00000030: 0xdd000000, 0x00000048, 0x00000000, 0x0000010f
Mar  3 10:38:19 localhost kernel: [93739230.557755] tg3 0000:08:00.0 eth2: 0x00000040: 0x00000000, 0xa5000000, 0xc8035001, 0x64002008
Mar  3 10:38:19 localhost kernel: [93739230.569808] tg3 0000:08:00.0 eth2: 0x00000050: 0x818c5803, 0x78000000, 0x0086a005, 0x00000000
...
Mar  3 10:38:23 localhost kernel: [93739234.611688] tg3 0000:08:00.0 eth2: 4: Host status block [00000001:000000df:(0000:0000:0a0f):(0000:0000)]
Mar  3 10:38:23 localhost kernel: [93739234.624030] tg3 0000:08:00.0 eth2: 4: NAPI info [000000c4:000000c4:(0000:0000:01ff):09d4:(01d4:01d4:0000:0000)]
Mar  3 10:38:23 localhost kernel: [93739234.699205] bonding: bond1: link status definitely down for interface eth2, disabling it
Mar  3 10:38:23 localhost kernel: [93739234.738410] tg3 0000:08:00.0: tg3_stop_block timed out, ofs=1400 enable_bit=2
Mar  3 10:38:23 localhost kernel: [93739234.850735] tg3 0000:08:00.0: tg3_stop_block timed out, ofs=c00 enable_bit=2
Mar  3 10:38:23 localhost kernel: [93739234.977285] tg3 0000:08:00.0 eth2: Link is down
Mar  3 10:38:25 localhost kernel: [93739236.081087] bonding: bond1: now running without any active interface !
```

1) as it occured at the same time for 2 distinct networks, we suspect a hardware issue (motherboard or microcuts in the power supply, ie power unit failing)
Feel free to tell me if you agree or not with my diagnostic ;)

2) a bond configured for active-backup is keeping a hot backup network card in case of failure. 
As you can see here it looks like it didn't run the backup and even didn't consider anything about. I checked the `ifconfig` at the time of the incident and the eth1 and eth3 (backup) were correctly attached to their respective bonds.

What could be the issue of the bond failing to switch to the hot backup card?

EDIT: full network config:

```
bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:b1:1c:xxxxx  
          inet addr:195.178.186.222  Bcast:195.178.xxxxxxx    Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: fe80::92xxxxa:4b1e/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11806289 errors:0 dropped:563346 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15209428 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:2314496738 (2.3 GB)  TX bytes:17247449206 (17.2 GB)

bond1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:10:1xxxx:ce  
          inet addr:192.168.0.1  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::210:18ff:fed3:b1ce/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:161091053340 errors:0 dropped:1071 overruns:0 frame:13821
          TX packets:112926434041 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:99357307904176 (99.3 TB)  TX bytes:45744253012472 (45.7 TB)


eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:b1:xxxxxx4b:1e  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11806289 errors:0 dropped:563346 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15209428 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2314496738 (2.3 GB)  TX bytes:17247449206 (17.2 GB)
          Interrupt:16 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 90:b1:1xxxxxx:1e  
          UP BROADCAST SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:17 

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:10:xxxxx1:ce  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:161091053340 errors:0 dropped:1070 overruns:0 frame:13821
          TX packets:112926434041 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:99357307904176 (99.3 TB)  TX bytes:45744253012472 (45.7 TB)
          Interrupt:48 

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:10xxxb1:ce  
          UP BROADCAST SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:52 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:6935638599 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6935638599 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:18028725295176 (18.0 TB)  TX bytes:18028725295176 (18.0 TB)
```

And here is /proc/net/bonding/bond0 (bond1 is similar)

```
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: fault-tolerance (active-backup)
Primary Slave: eth0 (primary_reselect always)
Currently Active Slave: eth0
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 100
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eth0
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 90:b1:1c:4a:4b:1e
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eth1
MII Status: down
Speed: Unknown
Duplex: Unknown
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 90:b1:1c:4a:4b:1f
Slave queue ID: 0
```

Comment: Can you add your configuration of the bond and the corresponding network interfaces.

Comment: Also include the contents of /proc/net/bonding/bond0 and bond1  (you may see your problem when posting these)

Comment: eth1 is down? how can ifconfig show me UP ?
Anyway ifup eth1 does not work :/

Comment: Your link on `eth1` is down. Check cabling and switch ports. If that is OK, check your configuration of your devices, not the output of `ifconfig`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. The cabling and ports are fine. How can eth1 be detected if link is down? Confit is the same as for eth0. Don't really know where to look

Answer (score 0):

Finally figuring out what the issue is when another issue appeared.
When that happened we called the datacenter to send a technician to verify ports and cables. The answer we got was that everything was fine and ports were blinking.

When I went myself to the datacenter for another issue I took a look at the cabling behind the machine... eth0 and eth2 were properly cabled, but eth1 and eth3 were not even plugged!!!! How could they miss that!

The morale of the story is that if a hot backup is up but fails to handle the failover, and nothing in the logs, then it is a cabling or port issue.
Also always check things yourself, don't trust others to do it for you, they will mostly not care